# Populate a boost tuple alternate way to this

Tags: c++, tuples

I am currently doing something like this

```
typedef boost::tuple<std::string,std::string> My_tuple;
```

Then when I need to put values in it I do the following

```
My_tuple tup  =  boost::make_tuple("StringA","StringB");
```

This works fine however I wanted to know what if I wanted to populate the string values later and not when I use `boost::make_tuple` what are my options ?

Comment: `boost::get<0>(tup) = "Hello"`?

Comment: @AndyProwl long time no see :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tuple is mutable and its `get` member returns a reference so, when you need to change the strings, simply go ahead and do that:

```
typedef boost::tuple<std::string, std::string> My_tuple;
My_tuple tup = boost::make_tuple("", "");

boost::get<0>(tup) = "StringA";
boost::get<1>(tup) = "StringB";
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, if you want to set all elements, use `boost::tie` function:

```
boost::tuple<std::string, std::string> t;
t = boost::tie("first", "second");
```